# How to write a shutdown function that's called when the corresponding jar is unloading

Tags: java

I'm building a jar which opens some *out of process* resources. (By the way, I must adopt this approach).

But what I want to do is close those resources - ideally using functions in my jar that I write - when the virtual machine is about to shut down that jar.

How do I do this? I'd rather avoid a JNI although the nature of the resoures are such that I've already confined this jar to windows only. Ugly I know.

Could I reliably rely on a singleton with a finalizer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot rely on finalizers, I would use a shutdown hook instead:

A very simple Example :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //Your shutdown logic here
        }
    }
);
```

If the code inside the thread grows, you probably should not use an anonymous class.
You can pass all your your resources to the thread and close them inside the thread.

More information can be found here : http://waheedtechblog.blogspot.de/2012/03/java-jvm-shutdown-hook-tutorial.html

Comment: +1 that will do the trick (and I need to read a java book from cover to cover). Thanks.